# Uninitialized constant in Controller with AjaxDatatables?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I used Datatable with ajax: https://github.com/antillas21/ajax-datatables-rails/wiki/Part-2-The-Datatables-with-ajax-functionality

My manage_datatable.rb:

```
class ManagerDatatable < AjaxDatatablesRails::Base
```

My controller:

```
class OrganisationNew::JobsController < OrganisationNew::OrganisationBaseController


def manage
respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.json { render json: ::ManagerDatatable.new(view_context) }
end
end
```

And my error:

```
!! #<NameError: uninitialized constant ManagerDatatable>
```

Any ideas?
Thanks for any help.

Comment: what is your file with  `ManagerDatatable` class name?

Comment: it is `/app/models/manage_datatable.rb` bro

Comment: @AvadaKedavra: Rename your `manage_datatable.rb` to `manager_datatable.rb`

Comment: but should be `/app/models/manager_datatable.rb` :)

Comment: aw. Thank you very much